# Multilingual Jekyll website running on multiple domains

Tags: cross-domain, jekyll, multilingual

I'm trying to setup proper solution for multilingual website generated using Jekyll. I checked some plugins and tricks without plugin. But still not sure how to achieve it. I found that it's possible to generate output of every language into subfolder. Eg.:

- `/en/` contains English version of website
- `/cz/` contains Czech version of website

But in my case every language will be published on own domain (example.com, example.cz). And this is the moment where I'm getting some troubles with the implementation. When I'll have every language in own folder (`/en/`, `/cz/`) this means that also {{page.url}} and parmalinks will contain that `/en/...` or `/cz/...` part.

Could you help me to find the trick I need to use? What is correct setup in this case?

---

Note: The only solution which is close to my situation is this https://frozenfractal.com/blog/2016/5/13/building-a-multilingual-website-in-jekyll/ Here is not possible to implement language switcher because solution excludes all files in alternative languages. (When I'll be on `www.example.com/contact` I need to be able to switch to Czech alternative `www.example.cz/kontakt`.)

Comment: I really don't see how you can solve this otherwise than having two jekyll with common templates. And two urls for one website doesn't seem logical to me.

Comment: Maybe I wrote my question inaccurately. But I think that this approach is quite usual. This is the page I want to transform from WordPress to static website: https://www.contentkingapp.com/contact/ and alternate version of this eg. https://www.contentkingapp.cz/kontakt/. You can switch between language version using language switcher at the bottom of page. I'm just thinking how to set everything in Jekyll and how to generate content for every domain.

Answer (score 0):

Two different urls makes sense to me. Google will have a different page rank for your sites, but that is the only downside I can think of. I would set the language and set alternate tags. You can use your page front matter to fill the alternate tags. If you succeed in building them from one repo, you might be able to automatically match the different language versions of your pages with an english page identifier (for your alternate tags). [Source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en)

Comment: I think that I wrote it inaccurately :) I will have every language version on separate domain. I was just thinking how to generate it on Jekyll site. My idea was to create folder for every language `/en/`, `/cz/`, ... and this I'll map these folder to domains. So `/en/` -> www.example.com, `/cz/` -> www.example.cz, ... But this won't work because all generated URLs contains that folder /cz/ as part of permalinks. I don't know how to solve that and set my build process correctly.

Comment: Yes... good question. Sounds like a logical and very nice solution. Unfortunately, I have never done that. I would also love to know how to set this up.

Comment: But I have to warn you that if David Jacquel says you should use two Jekyll repo's sharing the same theme... you probably should. He is right 99.9% of the time (when it comes to Jekyll).